# Why sympy Sum function can't evaluate this sum?

Tags: python, sympy

When I try to evaluate this expression:

```
f = sp.exp(-s*b*h*f)
sp.Sum(f, (s, 0, sp.oo)).doit()
```

all I get is symbolic representation of this sum. But when I try to sum over this:

```
f = sp.exp(-s)
sp.Sum(f, (s, 0, sp.oo)).doit()
```

it gives me exact result. For finite summation it gives exact answer even with additional symbols in exponent.

Comment: can you explain the differnces between the to code snippets, i don't see it

Comment: @D-E-N sorry, I made a mistake, it's correct now

Comment: You should open an issue in the SymPY GitHub repo:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Answer (score 0):

Whether the first series converges depends on the values of `b`, `h` and `f`. If the product `b*h*f` is either 0 or negative the series is divergent. For this reason, it is not possible to give a formula for the sum that will hold in all cases and sympy behaves accordingly

Comment: I tried to set those values as positive with assumption `f = sp.Symbol('f', positive = True)` and do this for  `b` and `h` also, but this also doesn't work.

Comment: @cover You are right, I guess this functionality has not been implemented in sympy.